# rsyncing files based on size

Tags: rsync

I am trying to rsync files with the extension *.scala and only those no other files between two directories. If the size is different they should be synced. I am executing this command and seeing no scala files being synced even though I know the sizes are different.

```
rsync -rnvh --ignore-times --size-only --include '*/' --include '*.scala' --exclude '*' /home/salilsurendran/code/servlet-app /home/salilsurendran/code/sbt-runs/servlet-app/
```

With the -n option I am doing a dry run and the output prints out a bunch of directories but not any files. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You were very close; as you need to move any file ending in `.scala`, not just any literal `.scala`, you need `*.scala` as the `--include`'s glob pattern.

Do:

```
rsync -rnvh --ignore-times --size-only --include '*/' --include '*.scala' \
    --exclude '*' /source/ /dest/
```

Answer (score 0):

rsync -nrvh --size-only --include="*/" --include=" * .scala" --exclude="*" /home/salilsurendran/code/servlet-app/ /home/salilsurendran/code/sbt-runs/servlet-app/ worked.

the issue was with the trailing '/' at the end of the from directory. Adding that made it work as I expected. Thanks.